# Magento2 Out of Stock Products are not display in category page

Tags: magento2, category, product-collection, out-of-stock

i have setup my site on magento 241 and out of stock products are not showing on category page, but it is showing on homepage widget section.
i also set display out of stock product options = yes from backend than also not showing .

does anyone have idea how can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Please execute `bin/magento cache:flush && bin/magento index:reindex` so that the information on out of stock products is added to Elasticsearch as new documents.

Comment: i already check with reindex but no any output

Comment: are they indexed at elasticsearch level? can you check if there are any documents for your out of stock products?